# passing db url as ajax parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, cherrypy

I have a controller written in python cherrypy that should check if a db url is valid by attepting to make a connection. I'm having problems however passing the parameter to the method. My ajax call is:

```
    $.ajax({ async : false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/settings/check_db_url/"+db_url ,
        success: function(r) { alert(r) },
        error: function(r) { alert('failure') }
    });
```

Now the problem the urls that I need to test are in the form of:

```
'sqlite':'sqlite:///Users/Home/tvb-database.db' or
'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:root@127.0.0.1:5432/tvb?user=postgres&password=postgres'
```

For the sqlite part I managed to pass it if I do something like:

```
    db_url = db_url.split('/').join('__')
db_url = db_url.split(':').join('x_xxx_x')
```

And then replace back in python. But this seems so hacky to me and for the postgress part I guess I'll have to replace some more. So what is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Wouldn't `encodeURIComponent()` do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send it as part of a POST parameter and not as part of the url using the `data` option:

```
$.ajax({ 
    async : false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/settings/check_db_url',
    data: { db_url: db_url },
    success: function(r) { alert(r) },
    error: function(r) { alert('failure') }
});
```

And in your server read the `db_url` POST parameter.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was missing.